# OpenRewrite: recipes example for adding a new key: value pair if a specific template matches in yaml

Tags: openrewrite

I have multiple yaml files, but we have to add a addition parameter only if specific template matches. Ex:

```
stages:
  - template: templates/my-java-service-v1.yaml@codeway
    parameters:

      lintingParams:
        skipSchemaValidation: false
      openJdkVersion: 17
```

Here `openJdkVersion` is an addition parameter should be added in existing yaml only if template `templates/my-java-service-v1.yaml@codeway` matches.
In current recipes only supports for a `sequencePath` match. but here I have same `sequencePath` for multiple places, so need to filter with specific template.

Comment: Hi Manish; sounds like you need a custom recipe that first finds the associated key & value, and then in calls out to AddProperty when found to add the new key & value. There is no way to do this using only Yaml; You will need a custom Java recipe.

Comment: @Tim It would be great if you can provide me any link, steps or any sample example for custom recipe for this scenario.